# Android make a Call programmatically without displaying a chooser

Tags: android, call, skype

My device has Skype installed. The App executes this code:

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + sMyNumber));
    startActivityForResult(callIntent, REQUEST_CALL);
```

But then a popup asks whether it should complete the action using Phone or Skype.

Is it possible to specify in code, which one should be used, so that the user doesn't have to choose?

Comment: Do you solved this question @Pawel?

Answer (score 2):

To always make calls using the Phone app, add this line:

```
    callIntent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster");
```

Comment: This could break in the future - not recommended.

Comment: It breaks on many devices, like 5.0+ Samsung high class phones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you:

```
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(videoIntent, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < activityList.size(); i++) 
{
    ResolveInfo app = activityList.get(i);
    //search for your app

    callIntent.setClassName(app.activityInfo.packageName, app.activityInfo.name);
}
```

But it is a bit dangerous, to ask for an application on the phone because may the app change their package name which will break your application in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this code worked for me

public void onClick(View view) {

```
            Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#*#2664#*#*"));
            startActivity(phoneCallIntent);

        }
```

// monitor phone call states
    private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

```
    String TAG = "LOGGING PHONE CALL";

    private boolean phoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            phoneCalling = true;
        }

        // When the call ends launch the main activity again
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

            Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");

            if (phoneCalling) {

                Log.i(TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());

                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                phoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that prevent the chooser from appearing?  Have you tried it on a system where there's more than one app capable of handling that intent?

Comment: This answer is exactly the **same** what the question mentions it **does not work**. Why are people writing answer without reading the question at all?